# Disraeli's "Never complain, never explain"

Tags: etymology, phrase-origin

The famous motto "*never complain, never explain*", that well represents an aspect of the English character, is said to have been coined by PM Benjamin Disraeli by most online source such as [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-phrase-never-complain-never-explain-mean) and [The Art of Manliness](https://www.artofmanliness.com/articles/never-complain-never-explain/) for instance.

[image]

(Pinterest)

Curiously I couldn't find evidence of when and on which speech or writing Disraeli gave the above expression.

Can anyone help provide details about when and on which occasion the motto was first coined?

Comment: [Rumor has it](https://www.newspapers.com/newspage/25990425/) this is also something William H. Stewart said :P

Comment: Hmm, he doesn't appear to have said it in Parliament. In 1892,  it was claimed that he had said "I make it a point never to complain," in the House.  Only he didn't because it's not in Hansard.  The phrase "never to complain" doesn't appear at all.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [*Dictionary of Modern Proverbs*](https://books.google.de/books?id=LPZfi4ADcusC&pg=PA42&dq=%22never+complain,+never+explain%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwie0dfm0IzbAhUGjSwKHezKDEQQ6AEISTAH) (2013), this maxim was attributed to Disraeli by John Morley in the first of his three-volume [*Life of William Ewart Gladstone*](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/21091) (1903), 222—23. Fortunately, this volume is part of the Project Gutenburg collection of scanned books. Unfortunately, however, the entire website is blocked for German IPs because of a copyright dispute, so I cannot verify the citation for you. But you should easily be able to do so by following the link I provided. Please come back and let us know.

The passage in question (p123), from the point of view of Gladstone in, I believe January 1835, reads:

> [...] To-day I am going to dine with the lord chancellor [Lyndhurst], having received a card to that effect last night.'
>
> It was at this dinner that Mr. Gladstone had his first opportunity of making a remarkable acquaintance. In his diary he mentions as present three of the judges, the flower of the bench, as he supposes, but he says not a word of the man of the strangest destiny there, the author of *Vivian Grey*. Disraeli himself, in a letter to his sister, names 'young Gladstone,' and others, but condemns the feast as rather dull, and declares that a swan very white and tender, and stuffed with truffles, was the best company at the table. What Mr. Gladstone carried away in his memory was a sage lesson of Lyndhurst's, by which the two men of genius at his table were in time to show themselves extremely competent to profit,—'Never defend yourself before a popular assemblage, except with and by retorting the attack; the hearers, in the pleasure which the assault gives them, will forget the previous charge.' As Disraeli himself put it afterwards, ***Never complain and never explain***.

Comment: Thanks, unluckily I can’t find the attribution on the pages 222/223 of the first of the three-volume you have linked.

Comment: (Suggested) edited in the relevant quotation (seems to be page 123).

Comment: @TripeHound - good finding, but that would still be reported speech, I think. .

Comment: @user3850720 Ahead of the edit being accepted, it _seems_ to stem from Lyndhurst (the lord chancellor) – possibly with the help of Disraeli – "_Never defend yourself before a popular assemblage, except with and by retorting the attack; the hearers, in the pleasure which the assault gives them, will forget the previous charge._", but _yes_ it's essentially hearsay.

Comment: @TripeHound: Thanks! I checked, but the wrong page number is in the source, not my iPad thumbtyping. The Project Gutenberg ban is really irritating.

Comment: Since this isn't a court of law, I'd call it anecdotal rather than hearsay, especially since there seems to have been two accounts of this particular dinner conversation.

Comment: The only other reference I've found is even more anecdotal. From a PDF of [André Maurois's autobiography _Disraeli: A Picture of the Victorian Age_](https://ia801600.us.archive.org/0/items/in.ernet.dli.2015.173976/2015.173976.Disraeli-A-Picture-Of-The-Victorian-Age_text.pdf) discussing c1861 André writes: "“_Forii
nihil difficile_ — to the brave, nothing is difficult,” he
used to say in those days. A child’s motto. Everything
is difficult. And for some time now he
had adopted another : “**Never explain, never complain.**”
Useless words must be avoided."